# Weird return statement in Lua

Tags: lua

I am browsing some Lua code on Github where I see several statements like

```
return Memory.value("game", "textbox") == 1
```

Does this "equal" this:

```
if Memory.value("game", "textbox") == 1 then
    return
end
```

or this?

```
if Memory.value("game", "textbox") == 1 then
    return true
else
    return false
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return` is a keyword, and does not have a condition as an argument, rather an expression. If you explicitly state `return` it WILL return. It evaluates it's arguments however, which is when the logical aspect comes into play.

I'm going to get into the logical aspect.

`==` is a comparison operator, it checks if it's arguments are *equal to eachother*. If so it returns true. So when used in a `return`, `return` will evaluate and return true if they are equal.

This is not limited to `==`, **any** comparison operators (`~=`, `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>`) will do the *exact same thing*.

`and`, `or` works a little differently however. They don't return true/false. Here's how they behave:

`return a and b`: This basically evaluates to *if a is true (neither false nor nil) return b*

`return a or b`: This basically translates to *if a is true (neither false nor nil) return a, otherwise return b

So as you could imagine, something like `return a and b or c` means

```
if a then
    if b then
       return b
    else
       return c
    end
else
    return c
end
```

So `return a and b or c` is the equivalent to `return ((a and b) or c)`

And for the sake of completion, `not` simply *evaluates it and inverts it*, so if it's false/nil it returns true, otherwise returns false.

Answer (score 10):

The `return` statement expects an expression as its argument. That means that if you write `return expression`, the evaluated value of `expression` is to be returned.

In this specific case, `Memory.value("game", "textbox") == 1` is an expression that evaluates to `true` if the return value of `Memory.value("game", "textbox")` equals `1`. If `Memory.value("game", "textbox")` was to be a value different than `1`, the expression would evaluate to `false`, which is what the `return` statement would return.

You could easily write the given statement as

```
if (Memory.value("game", "textbox") == 1) then
    return true
else
    return false
end
```

But as this is logically redundant, you would want to avoid writing this code and instead use the one liner you provided.

Answer (score 5):

Your question says that you know Perl. No, it's not like Perl, where the condition of `if' and similar statements can follow the statement.

`return` expects a list of zero or more return values. A function can return any length list. It can also have any number of return statements, and they need not return lists of the same length or meaning. So, the function's documentation is essential. See [load](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load) as an example.

This statement returns `true` or `false`.

It treats the value referenced by Memory as a table, indexes it with "value", calls the resulting value as a function with two string arguments and compares the result of the function call with the value 1.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression evaluates to true it returns so, otherwise it returns false.